# How to use the vehicle horn to communicate?

Tags: traffic, vehicle, regulations, noise

I know people use the car horn to get the attention of another drivers or pedestrians.

What other ways do people use the horn to communicate that may not be the same everywhere? Can you break any laws for using an automobile horn irregularly?

Comment: This question is too broad, and has four of the five votes needed to close it as such.  Are you interested in a particular jurisdiction?  Specifying a jurisdiction would probably save the question.

Comment: @phoog  which country uses there horns the most to communicate?

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK car horn use is restricted as per [Rule 112](http://www.highwaycode.info/rule/112) of the Highway Code as follows:

> **The horn.** Use only while your vehicle is moving and you need to warn other road users of your presence. Never sound your horn aggressively. You **MUST NOT** use your horn
>
> while stationary on the road
> when driving in a built-up area between the hours of 11.30 pm and 7.00 am
> **except** when another road user poses a danger.

the use of "MUST NOT" in the above rule indicates that this is a legal requirement - in this case the legal basis is [*The Road Vehicles (Construction and Use) Regulations 1986* reg 99](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1986/1078/regulation/99/made).

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, you can be fined for improper use of the horn

From the [NSW Road Rules](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=nsw%20road%20rules%20horn&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-au&client=safari) there are only three permitted uses:

- warning other road users
- moving animals off the road
- as part of a theft alarm or breathalyzer interlock

Comment: Did you give me an up vote?